# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in line 30

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm getting this error and I can't wrap my head around it.

The exact error message is:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/yetumedia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jt-travel-booking/styles/default.php on line 30

Line 30 is:

```
<?php if (! empty (get_post_meta( $post->ID,      'destination_short_info', true ))) { ?>
```

Here is the whole function:

```
<?php if (! empty (get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'destination_short_info', true ))) { ?>
        <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'destination_short_info', true ) ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need de declare a variable like :

$var = get_post_meta( $post->ID,      'destination_short_info', true ); 
if (! empty ($var){.....}

Comment: _[5.5.0 empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)_ You need to use version `5.5.0` or greater to use `empty()` like that.

Comment: Kelvin can you accept SJ Becker's answer. On Stack Overflow it is discouraged to put the answer in your question. You should instead "accept" one of the answers.

Comment: You are also very welcome to self-answer if you wish. I've rolled back the last question update, but the version containing the answer is available in the revision history if you want it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a note in the [Documentation for PHP's empty function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty()` only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`. Instead, use `trim($name) == false`

So it looks like you can:

1. save the value of `get_post_meta()` to a variable and then test with `empty()`
2. test with `== false` or `=== false` and not use `empty()` at all
3. upgrade to PHP 5.5 or higher

Comment: Thanks Becker, Updating the php version to 5.5 worked greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a function in empty test, so you need to get the result of you function in variable:

```
 $var = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'destination_short_info', true );
 if (! empty ($var){.....}
```

Comment: Sure can, you just have to have [PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or greater, I love it.

Comment: @Scuzzy I  work with php 5.6 and it does'nt work for me !!

Comment: `var_dump( empty( array_filter( array() ) ) )` will print _bool(true)_ for me

Comment: Thank you very much Scuzzy. Updating the php version to 5.5 worked greatly. Thank you too Mouaici